# For a given positive integer $n$, do there exist positive integers $x,y$ st $\phi(x)+\phi(y)=2n$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, totient-function, additive-combinatorics, goldbachs-conjecture

The question is: for a given positive integer $n$, do there always exist positive integers $x,y$ such that $\phi(x)+\phi(y)=2n$?

The case $n=1$ is good using $x=y=1$.  Assume $n>1$.  If we invoke Goldbach's conjecture, then yes the claim is true.  Let $p$ and $q$ be primes st $p+q=2(n+1)$.  Then $$\phi(p)+\phi(q)=(p-1)+(q-1)=p+q-2=2n.$$
But do we know anything about this equation without using the conjecture?  Thanks.

Maybe we can use what Keith Backman suggested that even nontotients are rare.  Let $n$ be an even integer $>0$.  So the set $S_n$ of even nontotients $\leq n$ is a "large subset of an arithmetic progression" and we might be able to use some sum sets inequalities to show that $S_n+S_n$ contains all even integers in $4,6,...,n$.  I still haven't found any useful results about sum sets to use.

Comment: Other than $1$, all odd numbers are nontotients. Even [nontotients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontotient) are relatively sparse. Any even number that failed to be the sum of two totients would have to feature every even partition into two summands containing at least one nontotient, which seems exceedingly unlikely.

Comment: Remark: [this question was also asked on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269814/on-a-relaxed-form-of-goldbachs-conjecture-proposed-by-erdős) a few years ago.

Comment: @GregMartin  Thank you for the reference.  Since the link says that it's an open problem, it would be great if you can post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.